# Avoid information messages in the output (coming from package comment)

Tags: warnings, comments, terminal-output, silence

I am using the package comment extensively and it produces a lot of information messages I don't want to read anymore. How can I get rid of them? (presumably, I would still like to receive warnings and errors, but not any of the messages that start with "Excluding".)

I've tried using the package `silence` but maybe it only addresses actual warning/errors and not pure information messages?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{silence}
\WarningsOff[comment]
\ErrorsOff[comment]
\WarningFilter{comment}{Excluding}

\usepackage{comment}

\excludecomment{hint}

\begin{document}
Zero
\begin{hint}
  One
\end{hint}
\begin{hint}
  One
\end{hint}
\begin{hint}
  One
\end{hint}
\begin{hint}
  One
\end{hint}
\begin{hint}
  One
\end{hint}
\end{document}
```

How can I avoid the MWE above displaying all these "Excluding 'hint' comment." messages in the output?

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/silence/silence.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/comment/comment.sty Excluding comment 'comment') Excluding comment 'hint' (./test.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd) Excluding 'hint' comment. Excluding 'hint' comment. Excluding 'hint' comment. Excluding 'hint' comment. Excluding 'hint' comment. Excluding 'hint' comment. [1{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
```

Comment: `comment` uses `\message` for the messages. `silence` can not filter them, and you can only get rid of them by either redefining the primitive `\message` or by redefining the `comment` definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment below the question you can redefine the `comment` definitions to remove the `\message` commands. You can patch a command using the `etoolbox` package, which provides the command `\patchcmd` with five arguments, first the command that you want to patch, then the part of the command that you want to modify, then the replacement text, then code to execute if the patch is succesful and as last argument code to execute if the patch fails. The final two arguments can be empty. In this case you want to replace the `\message` command with nothing.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\excludecomment}{\message{Excluding '#1' comment.}}{}{}{}
\excludecomment{hint}

\begin{document}
Zero
\begin{hint}
  One
\end{hint}
\begin{hint}
  One
\end{hint}
\begin{hint}
  One
\end{hint}
\begin{hint}
  One
\end{hint}
\begin{hint}
  One
\end{hint}
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/comment/comment.sty
Excluding comment 'comment')
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
Excluding comment 'hint' (./excludemsg.aux) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/
updmap/pdftex.map}] (./excludemsg.aux) )</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/ty
pe1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on excludemsg.pdf (1 page, 10669 bytes).
```

Alternatively, you can rewrite the macro to allow for an optional switch to display the message for some environments and not for others.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\renewcommand\excludecomment[2][]{\message{Excluding comment '#2'}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{msg}}{%
    \csarg\def{#2}{\endgroup \message{Excluding '#2' comment.}%
        \begingroup
           \DefaultCutFileName \def\ProcessCutFile{}%
           \def\ThisComment####1{}\ProcessComment{#2}}%
    }{%
    \csarg\def{#2}{\endgroup %
        \begingroup
           \DefaultCutFileName \def\ProcessCutFile{}%
           \def\ThisComment####1{}\ProcessComment{#2}}%
    }
    \csarg\def{After#2Comment}{\CloseAndInputCutFile \endgroup}
    \CommentEndDef{#2}}

\excludecomment{hint}
\excludecomment[msg]{otherhint}

\begin{document}
Zero
\begin{hint}
  One
\end{hint}
\begin{otherhint}
  One
\end{otherhint}
\begin{hint}
  One
\end{hint}
\begin{hint}
  One
\end{hint}
\begin{otherhint}
  One
\end{otherhint}
\end{document}
```

Result (the `hint` environments are not mentioned but the `otherhint` environments are):

```
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/comment/comment.sty
Excluding comment 'comment')
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
Excluding comment 'hint' Excluding comment 'otherhint' (./excludemsg.aux)
Excluding 'otherhint' comment. Excluding 'otherhint' comment. [1{/var/lib/texmf
/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./excludemsg.aux) )</usr/share/texlive/t
exmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on excludemsg.pdf (1 page, 10669 bytes).
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm in the process of adapting your answer to my actual use case (that also involves `\specialcomment` and `\includecomment`. Can you explain to me what `\def\ThisComment####1{}` does?

Comment: @Abdallah as described in the `comment` [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/comment/comment.pdf) in section 3.3, the `\ThisComment` command is used in the 'before commands' for a special comment environment. For a normal comment environment defined with `\excludecomment` this can be empty (i.e., `{}`) but it still needs to be defined because `\ThisComment` is called for all comment environments (not just the 'special' environments). The syntax with all the `#` symbols has to do with escaping,

Comment: normally you use `#1` to indicate the first argument to a function, but the definition of `\ThisComment` is normally done within another command (cf. the manual), therefore you specify `##1` to indicate that it is a literal `#1` and not the value of `#1` in the surrounding command. Now, in the definition of `\excludecomment` there is a double nesting, it is a `\def` inside a `\csarg\def` inside a `\newcommand` (or inside a `\def` in the original version), therefore you need double escaping with four `#` symbols.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanations!